# How to obtain reproducible but distinct instances of GroupKFold

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

In the **`GroupKFold`** source, the **`random_state`** is set to `None`

```
    def __init__(self, n_splits=3):
    super(GroupKFold, self).__init__(n_splits, shuffle=False,
                                     random_state=None)
```

Hence, when run multiple times (code from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html))

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

for i in range(0,10):
    X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
    y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    groups = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2])
    group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
    group_kfold.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

    print(group_kfold)

    for train_index, test_index in group_kfold.split(X, y, groups):
        print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
    print 
    print
```

o/p

```
GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
('TRAIN:', array([0, 1]), 'TEST:', array([2, 3]))
(array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]]), array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]))
('TRAIN:', array([2, 3]), 'TEST:', array([0, 1]))
(array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]]), array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), array([3, 4]), array([1, 2]))


GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
('TRAIN:', array([0, 1]), 'TEST:', array([2, 3]))
(array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]]), array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]))
('TRAIN:', array([2, 3]), 'TEST:', array([0, 1]))
(array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]]), array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), array([3, 4]), array([1, 2]))
```

etc ...

The splits are identical.

How do I set a `random_state` for `GroupKFold` in order to get a different (but repoducible) set of splits over a few different trials of cross validation?

Eg, I want

```
GroupKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42)
('TRAIN:', array([0, 1]), 
  'TEST:', array([2, 3]))

('TRAIN:', array([2, 3]), 
'TEST:', array([0, 1]))


GroupKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=13)
('TRAIN:', array([0, 2]), 
 'TEST:', array([1, 3]))

('TRAIN:', array([1, 3]), 
'TEST:', array([0, 2]))
```

So far, it seems a strategy might be to use a `sklearn.utils.shuffle` first, as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819598/scikit-learn-groupkfold-with-shuffling-groups). However, this actually just rearranges the elements of each fold --- it doesn't give us new splits.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold
import numpy as np
import sys
import pdb

random_state = int(sys.argv[1])


X = np.arange(20).reshape((10,2))
y = np.arange(10)
groups = np.array([0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

def cv(X, y, groups, random_state):
    X_s, y_s, groups_s = shuffle(X,y, groups, random_state=random_state)
    cv_out = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
    cv_out_splits = cv_out.split(X_s, y_s, groups_s)
    for train, test in cv_out_splits:
        print "---"
        print X_s[test]
        print y_s[test]
        print "test groups", groups_s[test]
        print "train groups", groups_s[train]
    pdb.set_trace()
print "***"
cv(X, y, groups, random_state)
```

The output:

```
>python sshuf.py 32

***
---
[[ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 8  9]
 [12 13]]
[1 2 0 4 6]
test groups [0 0 0 2 4]
train groups [7 6 1 3 5]
---
[[18 19]
 [16 17]
 [ 6  7]
 [10 11]
 [14 15]]
[9 8 3 5 7]
test groups [7 6 1 3 5]
train groups [0 0 0 2 4]

>python sshuf.py 234

***
---
[[12 13]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 8  9]]
[6 2 0 1 4]
test groups [4 0 0 0 2]
train groups [7 3 1 5 6]
---
[[18 19]
 [10 11]
 [ 6  7]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]]
[9 5 3 7 8]
test groups [7 3 1 5 6]
train groups [4 0 0 0 2]
```

Comment: I think this is a bug.  I opened a bug report.  If I have time after work I may go fix it myself.  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9323

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- `KFold` is only randomized if `shuffle=True`. [Some datasets should not be shuffled.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#a-note-on-shuffling)
- `GroupKFold` is not randomized at all. Hence the `random_state=None`.
- `GroupShuffleSplit` may be closer to what you're looking for.

A comparison of the group-based splitters:

- In [`GroupKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html), the test sets form a complete partition of all the data.
- [`LeavePGroupsOut`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeavePGroupsOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut) leaves all possible subsets of P groups out, combinatorially; test sets will overlap for P > 1. Since this means `P ** n_groups` splits altogether, often you want a small P, and most often want [`LeaveOneGroupOut`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html) which is basically the same as `GroupKFold` with `k=1`.
- [`GroupShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html) makes no statement about the relationship between successive test sets; each train/test split is performed independently.

As an aside, 
Dmytro Lituiev [has proposed an alternative `GroupShuffleSplit` algorithm](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9297) which is better at getting the right number of samples (not merely the right number of groups) in the test set for a specified `test_size`.

Comment: I see about `GroupKFold` ---I misunderstood randomization in terms of `random_state`.  I am confused about the difference between `GroupShuffleSplit` and `GroupKFold`. Eg with 3 splits, `GroupKFold`  produces 3 unique test sets. `GroupShuffleSplit` however might generate (with low probability) 3 test sets that are the same?

Comment: Does `GroupShuffleSplit` guarantee that the same groups are not represented in both the testing and training sets?  It would be nice to be able to specify `replacement=False`

Comment: Actually for this matter what's the difference between `LeavePGroupsOut` and `GroupKFold`?

Comment: Thank you for your edits, but I still don't see how to use this to produce test sets that form a complete partition of the data while also taking some `random_state` so that I can run this multiple times without getting multiple identical cv results.  The best option seems to be (suggested above) shuffling and then using GroupKFold, but this doesn't necessarily behave well I find when `GroupKFold` is wrapped inside a function.  `GroupShuffleSplit` is not really k fold cross validation and I am not sure whether it benefits from the same properties....

Comment: ...but I have read (eg, Elements of Statistical Learning) that splitting the data into random test train splits is *not* as good as cross validation.

Comment: I suppose I could find the number of groups *P* in each fold from *k* fold and then set *P* for `LeavePGroupsOut`, but I already have a trial I have run using GroupKFold, so I would like that to be my first experiment and now simply change the `random_state` to produce more iterations with different splits, but still using grouped cross validation as in my first trial. @joeln

Comment: I rescind the comment "this doesn't necessarily behave well I find when `GroupKFold` is wrapped inside a function."

Comment: If you want shuffled k-fold cross validation (e.g. repeated k-fold cross validation), it should be asymptotically identical to repeated Shuffle-Split. I don't have ELS lying around, but are you sure they're not talking about a *single* train-test split?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5396 might offer you an implementation (albeit with a deprecated API) with the shuffling you seek.

Comment: @user0 Why did you accept the answer if you "still don't see how to use this to produce test sets that form a complete partition of the data while also taking some `random_state`"? As for myself, I will be using @xvr's solution.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by user0's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152543/520709) (can't comment) but faster:

```
def RandomGroupKFold_split(groups, n, seed=None):  # noqa: N802
    """
    Random analogous of sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.split.

    :return: list of (train, test) indices
    """
    groups = pd.Series(groups)
    ix = np.arange(len(groups))
    unique = np.unique(groups)
    np.random.RandomState(seed).shuffle(unique)
    result = []
    for split in np.array_split(unique, n):
        mask = groups.isin(split)
        train, test = ix[~mask], ix[mask]
        result.append((train, test))

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution so far has been to simply randomly split the groups.  This could lead to very unbalanced groups (which I think `GroupKFold` was designed to ward off), but the hope is that the number of observations per group is small.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold
from numpy.random import RandomState
import numpy as np
import sys
import pdb

random_state = int(sys.argv[1])


X = np.arange(20).reshape((10,2))


y = np.arange(10)
groups = np.array([0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
for el in zip(range(len(y)),X,y,groups):
    print "ix, X, y, groups", el

def RandGroupKfold(groups, n_splits, random_state=None, shuffle_groups=False):

    ix = np.array(range(len(groups)))
    unique_groups = np.unique(groups)
    if shuffle_groups:
        prng = RandomState(random_state)
        prng.shuffle(unique_groups)
    splits = np.array_split(unique_groups, n_splits)
    train_test_indices = []

    for split in splits:
        mask = [el in split for el in groups]
        train = ix[np.invert(mask)]
        test = ix[mask]
        train_test_indices.append((train, test))
    return train_test_indices

splits = RandGroupKfold(groups, n_splits=3, random_state=random_state, shuffle_groups=True)

for train, test in splits:
    print "---"
    for el in zip(train, X[train], y[train], groups[train]):
        print "train ix, X, y, groups", el
    for el in zip(test, X[test], y[test], groups[test]):
        print "test ix, X, y, groups", el
```

Data:

```
ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
```

Random state as 4

```
---
train ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
train ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
train ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
train ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
test ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
test ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
test ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
---
train ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
train ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
train ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
train ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
train ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
test ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
test ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
test ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
test ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
test ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
---
train ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
train ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
train ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
train ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
train ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
test ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
test ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
```

Random state as 5

```
---
train ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
train ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
train ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
train ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
test ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
test ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
test ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
---
train ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
train ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
train ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
train ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
train ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
test ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
test ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
test ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
test ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
test ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
---
train ix, X, y, groups (0, array([0, 1]), 0, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (1, array([2, 3]), 1, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (2, array([4, 5]), 2, 0)
train ix, X, y, groups (3, array([6, 7]), 3, 1)
train ix, X, y, groups (4, array([8, 9]), 4, 2)
train ix, X, y, groups (6, array([12, 13]), 6, 4)
train ix, X, y, groups (7, array([14, 15]), 7, 5)
train ix, X, y, groups (9, array([18, 19]), 9, 7)
test ix, X, y, groups (5, array([10, 11]), 5, 3)
test ix, X, y, groups (8, array([16, 17]), 8, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Subclass and implement

a `random_state` dependent `_iter_test_masks( ... random_state = None )` method,
as was self-documented in the sci-kit `super(...)`'s source. The `random_state` parameter, used in instantiation ( `.__init__()` is 
"just" stored and left for user's creativity, if it will be or will not be used in any customised manner for a `test_mask` generation ( as literally expressed in sci-kit source comments ):

*(cit.:)*

```
# Since subclasses must implement either _iter_test_masks or
# _iter_test_indices, neither can be abstract.

def _iter_test_masks(self, X=None, y=None, groups=None):
    """Generates boolean masks corresponding to test sets.

    By default, delegates to _iter_test_indices(X, y, groups)
    """
    for test_index in self._iter_test_indices(X, y, groups):
        test_mask = np.zeros(_num_samples(X), dtype=np.bool)
        test_mask[test_index] = True

    yield test_mask
```

Defining a process, that becomes dependent on externally provided `random_state != None` ought also perform a fair practice to protect - save / store the actual current state of the RNG ( `RNG_stateTUPLE = numpy.random.get_state()` ), set the one provided from `.__init__()` calling interface and after having been finished, restore the RNG state from the saved one ( `numpy.random.set_state( RNG_stateTUPLE )` ).

This way such a custom-process gets both the required dependence on a `random_state` value, and  reproducibility.
**Q.E.D.**

Comment: I am not sure I follow; can you show on the toy example how it would be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

`GroupKFold` appears deterministic based on the group labels. So the solution is to assign new labels. I approach this by shuffling the list of unique group identifiers and assigning new labels from 0 to n_groups - 1.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

def get_random_labels(labels, random_state):
    labels_shuffled = np.unique(labels)
    # shuffle works in place
    random_state.shuffle(labels_shuffled)
    new_labels_mapping = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(labels_shuffled)}
    new_labels = np.array([new_labels_mapping[label] for label in labels])
    reverse_dict = {v: k for k, v in new_labels_mapping.items()}
    return new_labels, reverse_dict

random_state = np.random.RandomState(41)
X = np.arange(20).reshape((10, 2))
y = np.arange(10)
groups = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

for _ in range(0, 5):
    group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
    new_labels, reverse_dict = get_random_labels(groups, random_state)
    
    print(group_kfold)

    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(group_kfold.split(X, y, new_labels)):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        groups_train, groups_test = groups[train_index], groups[test_index]
        print("Split no.", i + 1, "Training y:", y_train, "Testing y:", y_test)
    print()
```

output:

```
GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
Split no. 1 Training y: [3 4 5 6 8] Testing y: [0 1 2 7 9]
Split no. 2 Training y: [0 1 2 7 9] Testing y: [3 4 5 6 8]

GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
Split no. 1 Training y: [3 4 7 8 9] Testing y: [0 1 2 5 6]
Split no. 2 Training y: [0 1 2 5 6] Testing y: [3 4 7 8 9]

GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
Split no. 1 Training y: [3 6 7 8 9] Testing y: [0 1 2 4 5]
Split no. 2 Training y: [0 1 2 4 5] Testing y: [3 6 7 8 9]

GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
Split no. 1 Training y: [5 6 7 8 9] Testing y: [0 1 2 3 4]
Split no. 2 Training y: [0 1 2 3 4] Testing y: [5 6 7 8 9]

GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
Split no. 1 Training y: [3 4 6 7 9] Testing y: [0 1 2 5 8]
Split no. 2 Training y: [0 1 2 5 8] Testing y: [3 4 6 7 9]
```

In the 10 samples, I made the first three belong to group 0, and each of the others belongs to its own unique group. The result is that the split is different each iteration.

The `reverse_dict` object is there to fetch the identities of the original labels.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to combine the code for groups k-fold and also wanted the same proportion of classes in the train and test set. So, I ran stratified k-fold over the groups such that same ratio of classes is maintained in the folds and then used the groups to place samples in the folds. I also included the random seed in the stratified to solve the different splits issue.

```
def Stratified_Group_KFold(Y, groups, n, seed=None):
    unique = np.unique(groups)
    group_Y = []
    for group in unique:
        y = Y[groups.index(subject)]
        group_Y.append(y)

    group_X = np.zeros_like(unique)
    skf_group = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = n, random_state = seed, shuffle=True)

    result = []
    for train_index, test_index in skf_group.split(group_X, group_Y):
        train_groups_in_fold = unique[train_index]
        test_groups_in_fold = unique[test_index]

        train = np.in1d(groups, train_groups_in_fold).nonzero()[0]
        test = np.in1d(groups, test_groups_in_fold).nonzero()[0]

        result.append((train, test))


    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

@user0

> Eg, I want
>
> ```
>    GroupKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42)
>    ('TRAIN:', array([0, 1]), 
>     'TEST:', array([2, 3]))
>
>    ('TRAIN:', array([2, 3]), 
>     'TEST:', array([0, 1]))
>
>    GroupKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=13)
>    ('TRAIN:', array([0, 2]), 
>     'TEST:', array([1, 3]))
>
>    ('TRAIN:', array([1, 3]), 
>     'TEST:', array([0, 2]))
> ```

This second split would split a group into both the training and test set. This is what GroupKFold is supposed to avoid. For example, in the second split an element from group 0 (indicies 0 and 1 in the dataset) is in both the training and test sets as indicies 0 and 1, respectively.

For the example you give, there isn't more than one way to do a grouped 2-fold split, since you only have 2 groups.